# Existence of continuous function with compact support

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and $E$ be a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ such that $K \subset E$ it is true that exist a continuous function $\psi$ with compact support such that $\psi \geq 0$,$\psi$ non trivial function, $\psi |_{K} =1$ and $ supp (\psi) \subset E$? 
I think to these is true when $E$ is open but for $E$ arbitrary I not sure,
Any help I will be very grateful.

Comment: @MW good observation, I made the edit in the post for non trivial jeje

Comment: Now it fails for $E=\{x_0\}$ where $x_0$ is any point.  Or more generally, fails for any set without interior points, and succeeds for any set with interior points.

Comment: Also, you never used anything about $K$ in your question.

Comment: @MW yep I forget say that the restriction of $\psi$ over $K$ is equal to 1

Comment: Ok, now it succeeds when $K$ is completely contained in the interior of $E$ (reducing to the case that $E$ is open) and fails whenever $K$ is not completely contained in the interior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, <s>suppose $E$ is not a neighborhood of $K$. Then there exists some point $p \in K \cap \overline {E^c}$. Suppose such a $\psi$ exists. As $p \in \overline {E^c}$, and support $\psi$ is in $E$, it must be that $\psi(p) = 0$. But as $p \in K, \psi(p) = 1$. A contradiction. No such $\psi$ can exist if $E$ is not a neighborhood of $K$.</s> Easier: Per ronno in the comments, If such a $\psi$ exists, then $\psi^{-1}(\Bbb R \setminus \{0\})$ is a neighborhood of $K$ contained in $E$.

Now suppose $E$ is a neighborhood of $K$.That is, there is some open set $U'$ with $K \subseteq U' \subseteq E$. For every point $p \in U'$, there is at least one open ball about $p$ that is contained in $U'$. Form the collection of all such balls, then *cut the radii of those balls in half*. The resulting collection of halved balls is an open cover of $K$ since every point in $K$ is the center of at least one ball. Therefore it has a finite subcover. Let $r$ be the smallest radius of any of the balls in the subcover. Every point of $k$ lies within one of the balls, which itself is contained in another ball of twice the radius that is contained in $U' \subseteq E$. Thus every point of $K$ is at least $r$ away from any point not in $E$.

Define for all $p \in \Bbb R^n, f(p) = \frac 1rd(p, K) = \frac1r\min_{q\in K} d(p,q)$. This is a continuous nonnegative function. Define $U = f^{-1}([0,1)) = f^{-1}((-1,1))$. Since $f$ is continuous, $U$ is open, and since every point in $U$ is within $r$ of $K$, it must be bounded. And since no point outside of $E$ is within $r$ of $K$, the closure $\overline U$ of $U$ is contained in $E$. Further, $f^{-1}(0) = K$ and $f^{-1}([0,1)) \subseteq U \subseteq E$.

Define $\psi(p) = 1-\min\{f(p), 1\}$. Then

- $0 \le \psi \le 1$ everwhere.
- $\psi$ is continuous, which is trivial to prove pointwise except on $f^{-1}(1)$, but even there it is not hard.
- On $f^{-1}([0,1]), \psi + f = 1$. In particular, $\psi^{-1}(1) = f^{-1}(0) = K$
- $\psi^{-1}((0,\infty)) = \psi^{-1}((0, 1]) = f^{-1}([0, 1)) = U$, so the support of $\psi$ is its closure $\overline U \subseteq E$. Since $\overline U$ is closed and bounded, it is compact.

Thus the result is true when $E$ is a neighborhood of $K$.

Comment: For the first direction, $E \supset \psi^{-1}(\mathbb{R} - 0)$ so is a neighborhood of $K$.